# How do I make it super customisable?

Tags: theme-development, wp-admin, users, theme-customizer

I can't find any info on this anywhere, maybe I'm not wording it right.

I've just started creating WordPress themes and at the moment I've implemented WP into my originally static website.

Is there a way to allow users/clients (if a theme was to be made for someone) to customise to the extent where I could give them options to:

- Browse and upload an image to place inside a certain element on the page (i.e. change the src of the file)
- Change the colour of all elements and fonts
- Tick or Untick show comments (so, when un-ticked, it removes the function call for comments in the theme, and when ticked it adds it back in place where I originally placed the code

(Preferably without having the user have to download a certain plugin but I'd just love to know how to go about doing it either way, if there great are any articles to read on it, videos, online guides or the like, would be greatly appreciated!)

Many thanks!

Comment: Take a look at Advanced Custom Fields, this will give users the options you need, you'll have to learn about how to integrate the custom fields into your template but the documentation is great. https://www.advancedcustomfields.com/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you're looking for is the [theme customizer](https://codex.wordpress.org/Theme_Customization_API). This allows you to attach settings to any element of your site you want. Just take a look at one of the WordPress standard themes to see what this looks like. You'll see that you can change colors, but also upload a new background image. Just follow the above link to learn how to implement the customizer in your own theme.

The customizer is typically used to adapt visual elements of the site. What it eventually does is insert css statements in the head of the page, overruling the main style file.

If you want to toggle the visibility of comments, you're not talking about inserting extra css, but change the template as it is assembled. A checkbox would typically be included in an [options page](https://codex.wordpress.org/Creating_Options_Pages) on the backend, although you could do this in the customizer as well.

**Summing up**, yours is a very common desire for theme developers. It's very well feasible, but you will probably need several days to get acquainted with it, providing you know your PHP.

(we're not into recommendations here, but if you google for 'wordpress theme customizer tutorial', you'll have plenty of choice)